# Google Maps API error: "UnauthorizedURLForClientIdMapError" ONLY FOR MY COMPUTER

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

We have authorized the proper URL for Google Maps and the map is able to load on other computers in the network. Yesterday, after authorization from Google, the map loaded on my desktop fine. Today, I get the `UnauthorizedURLForClientIdMapError`.

Others still have access.

I have cleared my cache, rebooted my machine, tried a different browser; none of these have worked.

Any ideas about what the problem could be?

**UPDATE**

The application uses windows authentication via .NET code. If I close the application without logging out, Google maps gives the error mentioned above when I log back into the web application. If I log out of the application and log back in, Google maps does NOT throw the above mentioned error. This is repeatable.

Comment: What is the URL that it is complaining about in the message?  Is that the one you authorized for that key?

Comment: @geocodezip yes, it is the one that I authorized for that key.